# Rest API failes to login when tried with Postman

Tags: laravel-5

I used this link http://localhost:8000/api/do_login? but it failed. Although when i freshly did it,it was working fine but later i started getting this error .The error was

```
{
"status": "unauthorized",
"message": "invalid credentials"
}
```

I used ngrok after that but its still same.login controller here

```
 public function login(Request $request)
 {

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|email|exists:customers,email', 
    'password' => 'required'
]);

if($validator->fails())
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $validator->getMessageBag()->first()
    ], 422);

$customer = customer::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if($customer and Hash::check($request->password, $customer->password))  {
    //authentication successful   
    $customer->access_token = $customer->createToken('login')->accessToken;

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'login successful',
        'data' => $customer
    ]);

}else {
    //invalid credentials
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'unauthorized',
        'message' => 'invalid credentials'
    ], 401);
}



   if( Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password]) ) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'-'.now());

    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token->accessToken
    ]);
  }
  }
```

API file

```
 Route::post('user_register', 'API\register@register');
 Route::post('do_login', 'API\login@login');
```

Comment: Can you `dd($customer)` before the if statement and share the results in the question?

Comment: {
    "status": "unauthorized",
    "message": "invalid credentials"
}

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comment. I think that it did not even access your controller method. That means that the route for your login method is auth-protected which would look like this:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
   Route::post('user/login', 'UsersController@login');
});
```

That will prevent any one from reaching to your method unless he is logged in. The solution is to get this route out of any group so that it is accessible.

Comment: Im using a controller

Comment: `Route::post('user_register', 'API\register@register');
     Route::post('do_login', 'API\login@login');     `

Comment: You mean you declaring your route within a controller? Can you share your routes file? I meant that in your routes file, you are using some kind of auth middleware that is intercepting your request.